# Insufficient permission to access file

Tags: windows-7, linux, vmware-player

I receive an error while powering on a VM:

> Unable to open file "D:\Virtual Machines\Red Hat Enterprise Linux
>   6\Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.vmdk":
>
> Insufficient permission to access file.

My system: Windows 7 32-bit with VMware Player.......some days it works but I (edited) did services run manually? Now am getting above error. What can I do?

Comment: have u tried starting virtual machine with admin permissions?

Comment: http://www.fixya.com/support/t18925727-vmware_workstation_error_insufficient I found the solution on another web site .It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Same error, I had taken over the PC from a past developer and tried local Admin logon, no help.

I first tried setting 'Full Control' security permissions in `Properties` for the project and file it was complaining about, no luck.

So I went up to the parent dir of all the VM's on the box, set 'Everyone' full control, and the VM opened right up.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, and neither 'Full Control' security permissions, nor running as admin fixed it.

It turned out the "Read-only" attribute of the file was checked and I only needed to uncheck it to fix it.

This read-only attribute tends to be set automatically when you burn the file on an optical media or when using disk imaging tools like Win32Disk Imager

Comment: In my case, RO attribute was on the folder containing the VM.

Answer (score 0):

You must give the VMware application "admin permissions" using your Mac's user admin account. At first, I tried adding permission to the virtual hard drive. That does not work. It must be added to the VMware application.

On Mac:

1. Go to the Applications folder.
2. Go to the VMware application.
3. Right-click VMware and go to "*Get Info*".
4. The Info window with "*Permissions*" (allowed users) for VMware will pop up.
5. Go to the bottom of the window and add a permission to list.
6. Enter your Mac password when prompted.
7. Click the *+* (add) button at the bottom of the window.
8. Add your username (user must be an "admin" user account) to the permissions list and set it to *Read & Write*.
9. Lock the permissions.
10. Reopen the VMware application.

You will find the error gone and your virtual machine will open. This worked for me after getting the "Vmware - insufficient permission" error.